# Is this article about exponential wrong?

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

> Wikipedia : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series
>
> Assume that the ring R has characteristic 0. If we denote by exp(X) the formal power series
>
> $exp(X)=1+X+\frac{X^2}{2} + \cdots$
>
> then the expression
>
> $exp(exp(X)-1)=1+X+X^2+\frac{5X^3}{6} + \cdots$
>
> makes perfect sense as a formal power series.

Shouldn't $R$ be a field, not just a commutative ring? Even if a ring $R$ has characteristic 0, the elements $2,3,4,...$ need not be a unit in $R$. Hence I think $\frac{X^2}{2}, \frac{X^3}{6}$,.. cannot be defined.

Am I right?

Comment: Well the commutative ring can be extended to a fraction ring. This would make those rational terms in the power series make sense without necessitating R being a field.

Comment: It's natural to require it to be a field (although not strictly necessary) and in order for the series to be sensible, you need some notion of convergence in your ring.

Comment: @rschwieb yes, I'm trying that right now such as giving a product topology of discrete topology and showing it is completely metrizable and etc..

Comment: You are right. Those fractions don't exist in $R$, and the series is not always an element of $R[[x]]$. However, often we can view $R$ as a subring of a $\Bbb{Q}$-algebra, where this would make sense. A semi-generic way of achieving that would be to consider $S=R\otimes_{\Bbb{Z}}\Bbb{Q}$. However, this fails sometimes. For example when $R=\Bbb{Z}[x]/\langle 2x,x^2\rangle$, the natural mapping $f:R\to S, r\mapsto r\otimes1$ is not injective.

Comment: There are rings extending $\mathbb{Q}$ which are not fields, and over which this example would make sense. You don't have to go to the full field-of-fractions that Laars suggests. The point may be that although you can invert formal power series in $R((X))$ that doesn't give you inversion of elements of $R$ itself. The invertible series have invertible constant term.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I think the only topology you need for $\exp(\exp(x)-1)$ to work is the $x$-adic topology, which you automatically have in $R[[x]]$.